Form won't change font color of TextFormField's after state change of variable that affects font color
I have a Form that, when filled and submitted with the correct answer, should change the color of the font of the Form's TextFormFields by changing the value of a variable _isAnswerCorrect in a setState, which is passed down to a stateless widget NumberInputField, which is a wrapper to a TextFormField.
So, in this context, there is something I really cannot understand. There is a similar question I asked here (I would like to keep all the issue there, but the comments don't allow much space) and the solution proposed there worked because the Form was reassigned at every rebuild.
However, if I don't allow the Form to be reassigned at every rebuild (see code 2 below), it does not work, i.e., the color won't change. But, at the same time, code 1 below works. Why is that? Why code 1 below works and the color is changed and code 2 does not. Shouldn't they be "the same" just written in different manners? If one could really help me understand the why here, I would appreciate.
Why this code (1) works?

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isAnswerCorrect = false;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void _answerIsCorrect() {
    setState(() {
      print('setting state');
      _isAnswerCorrect = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: NumberInputField(
                            isAnswerCorrect: _isAnswerCorrect,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                        Expanded(
                          child: NumberInputField(
                            isAnswerCorrect: _isAnswerCorrect,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                        Expanded(
                          child: NumberInputField(
                            isAnswerCorrect: _isAnswerCorrect,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Change Color?'),
                    onPressed: _answerIsCorrect,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NumberInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isAnswerCorrect;

  const NumberInputField({
    super.key,
    required this.isAnswerCorrect,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color fontColor = Colors.blue;

    if (isAnswerCorrect) {
      fontColor = Colors.black;
    }

    return TextFormField(
      style: TextStyle(color: fontColor),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: '?',
      ),
    );
  }
}

Why this code (2) does not work?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isAnswerCorrect = false;
  bool _shouldSetFormVisible = true;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget _form = Container();

  void _answerIsCorrect() {
    setState(() {
      print('setting state');
      _isAnswerCorrect = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_shouldSetFormVisible) {
      setState(() {
        _shouldSetFormVisible = false;
      });

      _form = Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: NumberInputField(
                isAnswerCorrect: _isAnswerCorrect,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            Expanded(
              child: NumberInputField(
                isAnswerCorrect: _isAnswerCorrect,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            Expanded(
              child: NumberInputField(
                isAnswerCorrect: _isAnswerCorrect,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  _form,
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Change Color?'),
                    onPressed: _answerIsCorrect,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NumberInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isAnswerCorrect;

  const NumberInputField({
    super.key,
    required this.isAnswerCorrect,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color fontColor = Colors.blue;

    if (isAnswerCorrect) {
      fontColor = Colors.black;
    }

    return TextFormField(
      style: TextStyle(color: fontColor),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: '?',
      ),
    );
  }
}

Thanks!

The problem of second code is related to _shouldSetFormVisible condition. In the first build you give this variable true value. According to your condition in further rebuilds, this section of your code won't rerun again:
_form = Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: NumberInputField(
            isAnswerCorrect: _isAnswerCorrect,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 20),
        Expanded(
          child: NumberInputField(
            isAnswerCorrect: _isAnswerCorrect,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 20),
        Expanded(
          child: NumberInputField(
            isAnswerCorrect: _isAnswerCorrect,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );

So you run setState by clicking on the button and the value of _isAnswerCorrect has been changed to true, but because of the value of _shouldSetFormVisible which is still false the whole condition get false, it won't run the body code. So the _form creation code won't run again to get the new value of _isAnswerCorrect variable.
I hope this explanation clears your mind. Feel free to leave comment if there is any ambiguity.
